How do I fix: Column 8 in UNION ALL has incompatible types: DOUBLE, STRING at [24:1]
I have the following query which is returning an error:
My code:
SELECT
    LOCATION,
    DEPARTMENT,
    MANAGER,
    SUPERVISOR,
    ASSOCIATE,
    FISCAL_DATE,
    AUX_NAME,
    ACTUAL, 
    PLANNED, 
    " " FSCL_YR,
    " " FSCL_WK,
    " " FSCL_MTH_NM,
    " " FSCL_YR_WK,
    " " FSCL_DT,
    " " ORG_NM,
    " " SRMGR_PRSN_NM,
    " " DIR_PRSN_NM
FROM
    `analytics-views-thd.CONTACT_CENTERS.CC_ASSOCIATE_AUX_USAGE_UNPIVOT`
WHERE
    FISCAL_DATE >= DATE '2024-01-29'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    " " LOCATION,
    " " DEPARTMENT,
    " " MANAGER,
    " " SUPERVISOR,
    " " ASSOCIATE,
    " " FISCAL_DATE,
    " " AUX_NAME,
    " " ACTUAL, 
    " " PLANNED, 
    FSCL_YR,
    FSCL_WK,
    FSCL_MTH_NM,
    FSCL_YR_WK,
    FSCL_DT,
    ORG_NM,
    SRMGR_PRSN_NM,
    DIR_PRSN_NM
FROM
    `analytics-views-thd.CONTACT_CENTERS.AGENT_METRICS` 
WHERE
    FSCL_YR = 2024

I have CAST the ACTUAL and PLANNED fields as STRING and FLOAT64 but I am still getting errors.
The error is  Column 8 in UNION ALL has incompatible types: DOUBLE, STRING at [24:1]
Please can you help me debug this error.

Welcome, could you share the schema of the two tables you are unioning? The error indicates that you have not correctly cast them to the same types, can you share how you have done this?

UNPIVOT - -
DEPARTMENT STRING
MANAGER STRING
SUPERVISOR STRING
ASSOCIATE STRING
FISCAL_DATE DATE
AUX_NAME STRING
ACTUAL FLOAT
PLANNED FLOAT
AGENT METRIC FSCL_YR  INTEGER
FSCL_HALF  INTEGER
FSCL_QTR  INTEGER
FSCL_MTH  INTEGER
FSCL_WK  INTEGER
FSCL_MTH_NM  STRING
FSCL_YR_WK  INTEGER
FSCL_DT  DATE
DEPT_NM  STRING
LOC_NM  STRING
MGR_PRSN_NM STRING

In the 2nd select table please use 0 as ACTUAL, instead of " "ACTUAL,. Also 0 as planned. These columns are a number in the 1st table.

Please don't add comments to clarify; code is hard to read in comments. [Edit] your question instead.
